# How to write less same code and make it better?

Tags: python

I have a few similar functions with lots of same code:

```
class One(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Text1', 'Text1'),
        ('Text2', 'Text2'),
        ('Text3', 'Text3'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name='Name1',
        choices=CHOICES,
        unique=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
        verbose_name = 'Name'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Names'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Two(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Text4', 'Text4'),
        ('Text5', 'Text5'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name='Name1',
        choices=CHOICES,
        unique=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
        verbose_name = 'Name'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Names'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Is it possible to write less same code and make it better?

I tried this:

```
class Choices(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (('.', '.'),)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name='Name',
        choices=CHOICES,
        unique=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class One(Choices):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Text1', 'Text1'),
        ('Text2', 'Text2'),
        ('Text3', 'Text3'),
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Name'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Names'


class Two(Choices):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Text4', 'Text4'),
        ('Text5', 'Text5'),
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Name'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Names'
```

But it does not work.
The error: You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'choices_ptr' to one without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

Comment: I think your question is more suitable here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your inheritance hierarchy is currently set up, you have three models: `One`, `Two`, and `Choices`. The first two inherit from the third one using [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). That is, `One` and `Two` have an additional field (called `choices_ptr`) which is a foreign key into the `Choices` table.

It looks like you *want* `Choices` to be an abstract class, silently providing fields and functionality to subclasses while not itself being a model with a corresponding table in the database. If that's the case, then you simply need to set [`Meta.abstract`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#abstract) to true in the parent, and it will exist only in Python as an abstract class, not as an instantiable model.

```
class Choices(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (('.', '.'),)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name='Name',
        choices=CHOICES,
        unique=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
        abstract = True # <-- Add this line :)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thank you, it works) but appeared another problem: field 'name' inherited from class 'Choices' with the `CHOICES = (('.', '.'),)`. I supposed that the field 'name' in classes One and Two would be with new `CHOICES`. Do you know how to fix it?)